# CSS: Is inline styling slower?

Tags: html, css, performance, html-rendering

Which renders faster?

```
// Just HTML
<div id="holder">
    <div style="float:left;">test1</div>
    <div style="float:left;">test2</div>
    <div style="float:left;">test3</div>
</div>
```

OR

```
// CSS
#holder div{
    float:left;
}

// HTML
<div id="holder">
    <div>test1</div>
    <div>test2</div>
    <div>test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both will be pretty fast. If you ask because of optimization, you should optimize somewhere else.

Comment: I guess the code with the inline styles should render a couple of micro seconds faster...

Comment: The tiny fractions of a second you might gain from doing inline styles will be lost many (many, many, many...) times over in the time you lose having to make style changes in multiple places.  Don't do that to yourself.

Comment: @galador Just for the record, I was being sarcastic `:)`. Micro second intervals cannot be registered by humans = there is no gain.

Comment: @Sime Hmm, I wasn't really talking to you specifically, but making a general statement.  Although, I see how it would be easy to interpret it like that.  :-)

Comment: Trust me, if you stack enough microseconds, you'll notice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In terms of actually displaying content, the speed differences between the two sections of code is negligible. Different browsers most likely have different implementations for rendering a webpage so the minute speed boost you get with one browser won't necessarily be reflected in another.

Now in terms of load times, it's a different story. Yes, inline styles are technically faster than an external stylesheet because you are making one less request on top of the page but using an external stylesheet is much preferred for code maintainability. It's only when you're loading multiple stylesheets that performance starts to become an issue since each time you refer to an new stylesheet the browser must submit another request. The solution? Simply concatenate stylesheets together into one.

Comment: If we were talking hundreds of Kb (or Mb) of HTML with inline styling, it would be a different story.

Comment: Hello from 2022... if the UI component is reusable, and it internally uses inline styles, then you've achieved reusability of inline styles, in a way. That is, you wouldn't be writing the same `style="float:left"` repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine (due to the HTTP-Request involved) that external CSS would be slower **but** inline styles are horrific for maintainability and negates the whole point of CSS which is to centralise values for colour and layout so you don't have to iterate through every element to change a style.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455488/comparison-of-loading-css-inline-embedded-and-from-external-files)

Comment: @Myles, I guess due to multiple http-streams it will be faster

Comment: @WaqasRaja I don't think so, multiple http streams only benefit from subdomains/cookie-less domains - as we don't know what images etc are on the page it is safer to assume external will be marginally (although negligible) slower. I believe the whole page is rendered by the browser (layout-wise, then CSS is applied anyway)

Comment: @Myles, did you notice why download accelerator is faster. Just because of multiple streams

Comment: @WaqasRaja Yes but this is not the same, you are ignoring my points, it is safer to assume it is slower as we don't know the content (image req's etc) of the rest of the page.

Comment: @Myles, Sorry for misunderstanding but I was focused on the code mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you assume that you don't want to use an external stylesheet, using a style tag in the <head> with classes on the elements will make an automatic inclusion easy later with a server-side programming language, rather than having dozens of inline styles. Unless you have a trivial numbers of styles, your total bytecount will be lower as well.

Check out Google's new 404 page: they even have the images in the style tag:

http://www.google.com/123412312

Answer (score 0):

In terms of browsing there shouldn’t be any difference you can test this with browsers' developer tools. Apart from code maintainability already mentioned in other answers, there is also the issue of specificity of inline rules. Since they have the highest specificity (1,0,0,0) they would override all other cascades. So you should carefully examine your use case rather than making the decision based on performance criteria