# Are separate css files always considered superior to inline styling? Even for one-off adjustments?

Tags: html, css

I have a fairly big single page application I'm working on. I can put the styles inline in the html tags, e.g. `<div style="width:10px"></div>`, or I can put it in a separate .css file and reference tags via classes or ids.

Obviously I'm using .css and classes/ids for styles (re)used many times. But there's a lot of one-off elements that just need a little specific adjustment here and there, e.g. a small margin to make it look just right, and creating a new class or id for each one of them seems extraordinarily cumbersome. I end up with lots of one-off classes and ids that are not easy to navigate, and instead of finding the style information where it's used (in the relevant tag), I have to go search in some random .css file.

Yet, the internet tells me it is always preferred to keep all my style information in .css files. Who's correct? Have I stumbled upon a specific case where inline styling is better, or would I somehow be shooting myself in the foot by doing that? Is there perhaps even a third way that is better?

Comment: Always ... of course not. Some coding situations require inlining (e.g. MailChimp campaigns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yet, the internet tells me it is always preferred to keep all my style information in .css files. Who's correct?

You do realise you're asking the internet here...? `;)`

Having had to redo several websites where styling had been applied using inline tags, I can say without any hesitation that I would never, ever use them myself. They are a nuisance to maintain and unless you're keeping a close record of where and what you have applied the inline styles, it is difficult to ensure that your changes to global css files will be respected throughout the site.

If you *do* need page-specific css classes and you don't want to put them in the global css file, add them to the page head in a `<style>` element. Putting all your css in a single file has the advantage that the users' browsers will load the file and cache it, so that it won't need to be reloaded on other pages of the site.

If you are finding you have a lot of tweaks to make all over the place, it suggests the design may need rethinking or refactoring. This is particularly the case with margins and padding--you can make a lot of work for yourself by choosing the wrong combination to apply spacing to your document elements.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence of the last paragraph.  Design your style the same as you do the page and KNOW why you do stuff for specific browsers etc.

Comment: seconded, and having thought about it I think you're right about the refactoring/rethinking

Answer (score 1):

Even for the one off styles I think a nice approach would be to have a specific file used during development called `oneoff.css` for example where you could have your style rules for one off situations.

This makes them easy to find and you get the benefits of having external .css files (separation of concerns, reusability even if you think you will never need to reuse I bet you will, and cacheability).

Answer (score 1):

You have to weigh the pros and cons in the context of your particular organization and applications. For example, standards are more important in a team environment than on an individual project or quick utility. Would inline styles on your pages be a surprise to someone making global changes?

For what it's worth, my large organization has a strict policy against inline styles, but in my opinion there's no definitive answer to your question. There's a good Stack Overflow post on this: [Comparison of loading CSS inline, embedded and from external files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455488/comparison-of-loading-css-inline-embedded-and-from-external-files)

Answer (score 0):

therefore define multiple classes and apply styles to an external file (`external.css`) is more orderly. however you can use online `<tag style="..."></tag>` or labels styles `'style'`
    `<style>some style</style>`, 
will not have any problem it is important to have the code neat and tidy. that's it