# What are the best practices for including CSS and JavaScript in a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know if it is advisable to embed (inline) all CSS and JavaScript that are required by a webpage, into  and  tags instead of letting the browser download these files. Is such a practice advisable?

My "application" is a SPA and I have managed to compile everything, even images and font-icons (as base64) into a single index.html, but I am not sure if this is a common practice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice would be to split each resources(scripts, CSS, images, etc.) into separate files. Which will allow browser to download and cache each resource for future reuse(even for other pages). But browsers have limit into six(on time of writing) parallel connections per one origin. That why a lot of external resources on page cause bad page loading performance and bad [waterfall](http://www.webperformancetoday.com/2014/03/18/waterfalls-101-how-to-use-a-waterfall-chart-to-diagnose-performance-pains/).

There are a lot of techniques to improve performance such as: bundling, domain sharding, image sprites etc. Also for some critical resources you can use inline technique. It allows browsers to use this resources instantly without additional requests. For example, you can embed all resources(image, CSS, scripts) that are required for loading indicator and browser will render it without additional requests.

For best development style do not embed resources and use separate files. In case you care about performance you should investigate waterfall of your page(e.g. [here](http://www.webpagetest.org/) or network tab in developer tool of any browser) and use some techniques to improve it. If you are interested in this field I recommend you to read books below:

- High Performance Web Sites by Steve Souders
- Even Faster Web Sites by Steve Souders
- High Performance Browser Networking by Ilya Grigorik

Note that this techniques are relevant only for HTTP 1.1. For HTTP 2.0 it will be only harmful because new version is designed to improve performance.

Comment: Thank you. I am investigating a solid strategy for the projects that will be built with BlendJS SDK

Answer (score 5):

You are ignoring some crucial things:

- Browser can fetch specific resources in parallel, thus reducing the time of load compared to the "pack altogether" approach.
- Browser can apply different caching policies for a different type of resources, which also can be used for some clever time and/or badnwidth reducing tuning.
- People can get some useful data even if not all resources are loaded.
- Not all functionality in SPA is heavily used, so sometimes it makes sense to load some entities lazily, on demand.

This is a very basic and simplified overview, there's a lot of thing to consider here. Moreover, budling to a bigger chuncks is actually something used in practice. Say, pretty often all js resources are bundled. But definitely trying to get rid of any additional http request will make your architecture less flexible, less cacheable and so on. So, it's overkill.

Answer (score 0):

No, always avoid inline-styling and scripting to reduce the page load of the html file. Also, separating your html, your css and your js keeps your coding clean, semantic and reusable for other external pages or applications that may require a common css property or script.

Comment: Yes, and reusable for other external pages or applications that may require a common css property or script

Comment: Reusability updated on the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's all about where in the pipeline you need the CSS as I see it.

1. inline css

Pros: Great for quick fixes/prototyping and simple tests without having to swap back and forth between the .css document and the actual HTML file.

Pros: Many email clients do NOT allow the use of external .css referencing because of possible spam/abuse. Embedding might help.

Cons: Fills up HTML space/takes bandwidth, not resuable accross pages - not even IFRAMES.

2. embedded css

Pros: Same as above regarding prototype, but easier to cut out of the final prototype and put into an external file when templates are done.

Cons: Some email clients do not allow styles in the [head] as the head-tags are removed by most webmail clients.

3. external css

Pros: Easy to maintain and reuse across websites with more than 1 page.

Pros: Cacheable = less bandwidth = faster page rendering after second page load

Pros: External files including .css can be hosted on CDN's and thereby making less requests the the firewall/webserver hosting the HTML pages (if on different hosts).

Pros: Compilable, you could automatically remove all of the unused space from the final build, just as jQuery has a developer version and a compressed version = faster download = faster user experience + less bandwidth use = faster internet! (we like!!!)

Cons: Normally removed from HTML mails = messy HTML layout.

Cons: Makes an extra HTTP request per file = more resources used in the Firewalls/routers.

Source/Reference : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455488/comparison-of-loading-css-inline-embedded-and-from-external-files)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping all the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code in one file can make it difficult to work with. Stylesheet and JavaScript files must contain the  and  tags respectively, because they are HTML snippets and not pure .css or .js files.

Many web developers recommend loading JavaScript code at the bottom of the page to increase responsiveness, and this is even more important with the HTML service. In the NATIVE sandbox mode, all scripts you load are scanned and sanitized client-side, which may take a couple of seconds. Moving your  tags to the end of your page will let HTML content render before the JavaScript is processed, allowing you to present a spinner or other message to the user.

When you're hard at work on your markup, sometimes it can be tempting to take the easy route and sneak in a bit of styling.

I'm going to make this text red so that it really stands out and makes people take notice!

Sure -- it looks harmless enough. However, this points to an error in your coding practices.
Instead, finish your markup, and then reference that P tag from your external stylesheet.

## someElement > p {  color: red;}

Remember -- the primary goal is to make the page load as quickly as possible for the user. When loading a script, the browser can't continue on until the entire file has been loaded. Thus, the user will have to wait longer before noticing any progress.

If you have JS files whose only purpose is to add functionality -- for example, after a button is clicked -- go ahead and place those files at the bottom, just before the closing body tag. This is absolutely a best practice.