# Where is it preferable to specify the width of tables - in HTML or CSS class?

Tags: html, css, class, attributes

I read somewhere that the site should be working even without CSS files.

What would be better?

```
<table width=500>
```

or

```
my-table {
   width: 500px;
   min-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparison of loading CSS inline, embedded and from external files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455488/comparison-of-loading-css-inline-embedded-and-from-external-files)

Answer (score 1):

The width attribute is deprecated for use on a table element. See for example [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

> Deprecated
>
> width
> This attribute defines the width of the table. Use the CSS width property instead.

Comment: What if I do it like this?
<table style="width: 500px">
Or should I put ALL the styles in a CSS file anyway?

Comment: It depends on your use case. Often putting the CSS in a file to separate it out from the HTML is useful, particularly to help future maintenance, but there are occasions where this won't work (e.g. some email clients only obey inline styling).

Answer (score -1):

Depends on your preference. Do you need the styling to be rendered with the HTML (before the CSS file is loaded).

I would prefer to do it in an external stylesheet, but the above is the only use case I can think of where it makes sense to do it inline.

Comment: I think you may be mixing up the attribute called width and the possibility of doing inline styling using a style attribute and CSS width property.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What about this? <table style="width: 500px">